# stripe checkout custom button not charging

Tags: javascript, php, checkout, stripe-payments

I am trying to get Stripe's Checkout Custom Button to charge a credit card but all it does is minimize after I enter the credit card details. I am using the code found in the documentation but I can't get it to work. The simple button is easy to use and I figured it would be as easy as just customizing that one but it's very different.

Here's the code:

**Payment Page**

```
<form action="charge.php" method="post">
            <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
            <input type="submit" value="Pay with card" id="customButton"/>
            <?php require_once('./config.php'); ?>
                <script>
                var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                    key: '<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>',
                    image: 'favicon.png',
                    token: function(token, args) {
                    // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
                    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
                    }
                });

                document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    // Open Checkout with further options
                    handler.open({
                    name: 'Imprintnation',      
                    description: 'Decals',
                    amount: <?php echo $stripeTotal; ?>

                });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                </script>
                </form>
```

**Charge Page(charge.php)**

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');

$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
  'email' => 'customer@example.com',
  'card'  => $token
));

$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
  'customer' => $customer->id,
  'amount'   => 5000,
  'currency' => 'usd'
));

echo '<h1>Successfully charged $5!</h1>';
?>
```

**Configuration Page(config.php)**

```
<?php
require_once('./lib/Stripe.php');

$stripe = array(
secret_key      => 'sk_test_************************',
publishable_key => 'pk_test_************************'
);

Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

What am I missing here? I can't even get it to retrieve a token.

**How can I retrieve a token and charge a card?**

Comment: presumably you would have to set a callback page on stripe.com and direct them to your `charge.php` that would get you the token, im assuming stripe works similar to paypal, i did not check

Comment: This is directly from their documentation and it doesn't mention anything about setting up a callback page.

Comment: you could try `var_dump($charge)` to see if anything got returned. also check your server has a curl extension installed for php, it will need it to interact with their server

Comment: It appears they callBack to the same page from which you made the post so you're probably right, no need to configure that https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms#create-a-single-use-token

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally got it to work. Had to change a bunch of it. Here is the code:

**Payment page**

```
<form action="charge.php" method="post">
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 

<button id="customButton">Pay with Card</button>
<style>
#customButton{
width:300px;
height:50px;
background-color:orange;
color:white;
border:2px solid green;
}
</style>
 <script>
 $('#customButton').click(function(){
 var token = function(res){
 var $input = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />').val(res.id);
 $('form').append($input).submit();
 };

 StripeCheckout.open({
 key:         '<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>',
 address:     false,
 amount:      '<?php echo $price; ?>',
 currency:    'usd',
 name:        'test',
 description: '<?php echo $desc; ?>',
 panelLabel:  'Checkout',
 token:       token
 });

 return false;
 });
 </script>
 <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="<?php echo $desc; ?>"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="totalPrice" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"/>
</form>
```

**charge.php**

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');

$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$amount = $_POST['totalPrice'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];
$percent = "0.01";
$realAmount = $amount * $percent;
try {       
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    'card' => $token,
    'amount'   => $amount,  
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'description' => $desc
    ));

    } catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
// The card has been declined
}

echo "<h1>Successfully charged $$realAmount!</h1>";
?>
```

I wish Stripe's documentation was more straightforward but this code handles the charge and it logs it on your dashboard.

Comment: You should never pass the total price/amount value across in a form via the client - anyone could change the value client-side before sending.

Answer (score 1):

@BlueSix is right, why do you have:

`<input type="hidden" name="totalPrice" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"/>`

Just because the value is hidden, does not mean it cannot be edited by the end user.

It would be much better to set `$amount = $price` directly, passing the variable through your application backend.